# Flutter HTTP request using Basic Auth + passing user and password to receive user data back

Tags: web-services, flutter, dart

I am a newcomer, not a professional coder (so be gentle), trying to build a Flutter app that must connect to a web/server API in HTTP.
According to the doc, to make a connection a header must be used, this header uses the Basic Ath method, with login and password + a content type.
Till that point I think I have found how to do (see code snippet hereunder) but I have to send a user id and a user password to the API in order to receive back user data. And I must humbly confess that I am stuck there...
I thank you in advance for your help!
Bernard

My code (after importing dart:convert et package:http/http.dart + installed the required dependencies) :

```
void brol() async {
String username = 'user';
String password = 'pass';
String userpass = '$username:$password';
String basicAuth =
'Basic ' + userpass;
print(basicAuth);
Response r = await get('https://www.adresse/login.php',
headers: {'authorization': basicAuth});
}
```

Many Thanks in advance for your answer,
Bernard

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass basic auth credentials in API call for a Flutter mobile application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50244416/how-to-pass-basic-auth-credentials-in-api-call-for-a-flutter-mobile-application)

Comment: You need to base64 the credentials - see linked question/answer

Answer (score 2):

Your credentials should be in base64. You can visit the [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50244616/8342742) in the comment.

Your code should be look like this:

```
main() async {
  String username = 'user';
  String password = 'pass';
  String basicAuth =
      'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode('$username:$password'));
  print(basicAuth);

  Response r = await get('https://www.adresse/login.php',
      headers: <String, String>{'authorization': basicAuth});
  print(r.statusCode);
  print(r.body);
}
```

See also [this blog post](https://hagenverfolgt.medium.com/basic-http-auth-with-flutter-the-right-way-e5209cbe4b55).