# Flutter http Post - StatusCode 401 - repetition of response

Tags: php, http, flutter

I have some trouble with my Http Post Request in Flutter. I must connect to a PHP web service (using a header) and post some user/password info to get a response (here, user info).
I believe I am near to the solution but I still get a `StatusCode 401` as response despite the fact that it works when I try with Postman (with same credentials).

Here is the code of the function I call :

```
Future<http.Response> post() async {

  var url = "https://www.monadresse/login.php";
  String password = "xxx";
  String username = "yyy";
  //var bytes = utf8.encode("$username:$password");
  var bytes = "$username:$password";
  String userNameUser = "www";
  String passwordUser = "zzz";
  var passwordUserEncoded = base64.encode(utf8.encode(passwordUser));
//var passwordUserEncoded = base64.encode(passwordUser);
  var headers = {
    "Authorization": "Basic $bytes",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  };
  var requestBody = json.encode({ 'user': userNameUser, 'password': passwordUserEncoded});
  print(headers);
  print(requestBody);

  final http.Response response = await http.post(
    url,
    body: requestBody,
    headers: headers,
  );
  if(response.statusCode == 200){
    var responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
    print(Utf8Codec().decode(response.bodyBytes));

    print("Body: " + responseJson);}

  print(bytes);
  print(passwordUserEncoded);
  print(response.statusCode);
  print("Fini");
}
```

Another weird thing (read 'I don't understand')... I have added some prints to have an idea of what's happening and, as you can see hereunder, the 2 first prints (located before the request) are first printed twice and after that the 3 last prints are also repeated twice.

```
flutter: {Authorization: Basic yyy:xxx, Content-Type: application/json}
flutter: {"user":"www","password":"zzz"}
flutter: {Authorization: yyy:xxx, Content-Type: application/json}
flutter: {"user":"www","password":"zzz}
flutter: yyy:xxx
flutter: zzz
flutter: 401
flutter: Fini
flutter: yyy:xxx
flutter: zzz
flutter: 401
flutter: Fini
```

As I don't find a solution on the net I very hope someone will help me.

Comment: You need to utf8 encode, then base 64 encode the username:password string.

Comment: Thanks Richard for your answer!
I tried with utf8encode - base64 but didn't word neither...
I'll search for your answer, don't have time now...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50244416/how-to-pass-basic-auth-credentials-in-api-call-for-a-flutter-mobile-application/50244616#50244616

Comment: Thaks Richard
It works!
I didn't knew headers had to be utf8-base64 encoded (I tried before but in the wrong order)

Comment: In general, headers do not. The form of the basic authentication header is: Authorization -> Basic AAAAAAAAA, where AAAAA is the base64 encode of username:password in utf8. (Note how the word Basic is in plain text.

Comment: Many Thanks, It works almost fine now.
Almost because I still have the repetition of my answer. I receive it twice. Any idea of the reason?

Comment: My guess would be that you are calling `post` twice.

Comment: I checked but not... I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the cause of this issue is that the `'username:password'` used in the authorization header isn't encoded to base64.

Here's a working sample for basic authentication using [test endpoints from Postman](https://docs.postman-echo.com/#df815c41-a76b-4b5b-7129-ea59275f254b). The username is `postman` and the password is `password`.

```dart
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert' show utf8, base64;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var _usernameTextController = TextEditingController();
  var _passwordTextController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                controller: _usernameTextController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Username',
                ),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                controller: _passwordTextController,
                obscureText: true,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Password',
                ),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                child: Text('Login'),
                onPressed: _doLogin(_usernameTextController.text, _passwordTextController.text),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ), 
    );
  }

  _doLogin(String username, String password) {
    if (username.trim().isEmpty || password.trim().isEmpty) {
      debugPrint('Either username or password is empty');
    } else {
      _login(username, password)
          .then((value) => debugPrint('Login finished $value'))
          .catchError((error) => debugPrint('Login error: $error'));
    }
  }

  Future _login(String username, String password) async {
    // 'username:password' is base64 encoded
    var authHeader = '${base64.encode(utf8.encode('$username:$password'))}';
    debugPrint('userpass: ${username + password}');
    debugPrint('authHeader: $authHeader');
    final response = await http.get(
      'https://postman-echo.com/basic-auth',
      headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Basic $authHeader"},
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
      // then parse the JSON.
      return response.body;
    } else {
      // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
      // then throw an exception.
      throw Exception(
          'Failed to login [${response.statusCode}] ${response.body}');
    }
  }
}
```