# .net-core api session is not stable in flutter requests

Tags: asp.net-core, flutter, dart-html

I have a webApi .net core. I use this api also for angular 7. 
In api sessions are not stable. I solve ths proble `'withCredentials': true`. for angular 7.
But for Flutter I can not find anything like that.

I tried `import 'dart:html';`. But I get

```
Target of URI doesn't exist: 'dart:html'.
Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or Try using a URI for a file that does exist.dart(uri_does_not_exist)
```

error

is there any way to set `withCredentials:true` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass basic auth credentials in API call for a Flutter mobile application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50244416/how-to-pass-basic-auth-credentials-in-api-call-for-a-flutter-mobile-application)

Comment: Hi @RichardHeap. I can post and get data from api. the problem is about session. I set session in .net core and when I request for another method session is null. I use same api for angular 7. I also had this problem in angular. I set `'withCredentials': true` in angular. I look for like this solution in flutter also

Comment: The session is probably maintained by a session cookie, which you need to return with each subsequent request. Search for [dart] cookie for examples.

Comment: @RichardHeap thanks for your advice. I solved the problem with dio. `var dio = new Dio();
dio.interceptors.add(CookieManager(CookieJar()))`