# How to pass basic authentication in flutter?

Tags: flutter

In my flutter app I would like to implement basic authentication. The project is like user need to login to the app, after the login they have to give a test. After successful login using Django knox authentication(a token is generated for login) when the Test page comes, Basic authentication need to implement.

Here is the following code snippet.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

Future TestAPI(String question1, String question2, String question3, String question4) async{

String url = 'https://someapi.com/api/test/';
String username = "myusername";
String password = "mypassword";
String basicAuth =
  'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode('$username:$password'));

var response = await http.post(url,
  headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": basicAuth
      },
  body: jsonEncode(
        {
        "question1":question1,
        "question2":question2,
        "question3":question3,
        "question4":question4,
        }
    )
);
var convertedDataToJson = json.decode(response.body);
return convertedDataToJson;
```

I want to use dynamic username and password. How can I implement the logic??

I have gone through [this logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50244416/how-to-pass-basic-auth-credentials-in-api-call-for-a-flutter-mobile-application) but this is not what I am looking for. Can anyone help to solve this problem?

Comment: Why don't you pass the username and password to the function as a parameter? Or what is it you want to achieve and this example doesn't help you?

Comment: by using username and password the user is already logged in. By using those username and password i want to  implement the basic auth. can you tell me how can I do this? I am new in flutter. Can you help to solve this?