# How to do Basic auth to get token using Dio Flutter

Tags: flutter, api, dio

Good day everyone

I would love assistance with doing post API call using basic auth to get the response like the screenshot attached. Thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2ct3.png)

Comment: Take a look on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50244416/how-to-pass-basic-auth-credentials-in-api-call-for-a-flutter-mobile-application

Comment: Have a look into this solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/50244616/7557223